# Clean install of 14.04 on Dell Vosro 400 with dual screen setup boots to black screen with working cursor

Tags: boot, nvidia

I am installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit on my Dell Vostro 400, but upon every attempt to boot, I only get a black screen with a working cursor. It is set up with a Nvidia GeForce 7300 LE videocard (didn't originally come with the computer) and two monitors, which I am afraid may somehow be causing the problem. I used to have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit with Xorg drivers for the card, but I formatted the hard drive, which should have completely removed them. Any ideas? I really need this computer before school starts on September 2nd. Just a side note, the bug may have been fixed since I made the installation DVD, which was made just before 14.04.1 came out.

**New information**

I have tried installing different versions of Ubuntu in my free time, and so far, Ubuntu 12.04.3 has worked. But it is still having problems, mainly that according to its display settings, it thinks it is on a laptop, when it is really on a desktop. It also does not recognize my other monitor. However, both displays are mirrored with the Ubuntu logo and the loading dots that change color during startup and shutdown. Now what? I'll settle for Ubuntu 12.04, and maybe even 10.04 if it will work.

**Newer Information**

I finally got Ubuntu 12.04 to work, even though it's not the version I was hoping for. All I had to do was go into the Additional Drivers program, and install the "(recommended)" version of the driver. Then after a reboot, my second monitor was recognized, and my desktop was extended on to it.

Comment: Is the cursor a mouse cursor or the underscore cursor like you would see in a terminal? Also, does `Ctrl+Alt+F1` get you to a terminal prompt? You can return to the GUI with `Ctrl+Alt+F7` if needed.

Comment: By cursor, I mean a mouse cursor. And it works and moves when I move the mouse. I can't check on the control combinations right now.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 does bring up a prompt. Ctrl+Alt+F7 takes me back. What should I do with the prompt? Also, I've tried re-installing, installing 12.04, with same result, also unplugging one monitor before installation, and taking videocard out before install (boots fine first time, but putting videocard back in and connecting monitors has same problem).

Comment: You installed, are installing or what?

Comment: I was attempting to install.